# Install python dependencies with a specific version in a dynamic way

Tags: python, pip, installation, requirements.txt

sorry if title is not clear. My problem is quite simple indeed but not sure if there is a solution out there:

I have requirements files with specific versions for each package (these requirements.txt files are also used by tox to execute pytest for py27 and py36).

Problem is that there is a python wrapper for a C library that must be installed with same version:
e.g. libawesomecbinaries-2.2.3  ==> pip install awesomepythonwrapper==2.2.3

The lib comes with a awesomec-config --version to check version installed.
Is there a way to instruct pip, tox and all the nice python tools to install a package with a specific version? Or do I have to use a bash script for that?

Comment: Just chiming in with a: this is where could docker shine :) Where `pip` handles your python dependencies nicely, docker handles *all* your dependencies nicely.

Comment: You can not do that with a `requirements.txt` file but the dependencies in `setup.py` can be calculated dynamically.

Comment: @smassey we also have a docker image and indeed we solved it:) issue is managing a dev environment in a more fluid way.

Comment: Is `libawesomecbinaries` a C/C++ library or is it another Python package uploaded to PyPI?

Comment: @hoefling it is a C/C++ lib which has got a python wrapper. You can build it from source (along with its python package) or you can install it with yum/apt-get and then install the PyPi package.

Comment: You can build the wrapper into a fat wheel with the lib bundled inside, this would pin the lib version implicitly. No matter what is installed system-wide, the python wrapper uses its own lib version.

Comment: @hoefling thanks! will try this way and let you know!